# Angular combine data from multiple http requests

Tags: angular, httpclient

I want to to get data for several different ProductIds from an remote source using httpClient within an angular service.
I want to combine the data within the service and then return it.

Using just one productId, this works just fine:

```
getData(productId: string): Observable<any> {
  const path = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'productId=' + productId;
  return this.httpClient.get(path);
}
```

But how can I iterate over an array of product Ids and then return the combined result?

```
getData(productIds: Array<string>): Observable<any> {
  let data: Array<string>;

  productIds.forEach(element => {
     const path = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'productid=' + element;
     data.push(this.httpClient.get(path));
  });

  return data;
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Me personally I'd create a REST endpoint on the server to which you can post the array of IDs so a single HTTP call (and probably a single database query) can return all the products necessary... Like this it is very performance intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ask for different products in parallel you can use forkJoin operator:

```js
getData(productIds: Array<string>): Observable<any> {  
  const data = productIds.map(element => {
     const path = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'productid=' + element;
     return this.httpClient.get(path);
  };
  return forkJoin(...data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin)

[P.S.] the code below is not tested

```
 let productAPIs = [1,2,3,4];

 productIds.forEach(element => {
    const path = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'productid=' + element;
    productAPIs.push(this.http.get(path);
 });


 forkJoin(productAPIs).subscribe(results => {
    // results[0] is your productId[0]
    // results[1] is your productId[1]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [the zip function from RXJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html). It combines all the results from different observables into an array.

```
getData(productIds: Array<string>): Observable<any> {
  let data: Array<Observable<any>>;

  productIds.forEach(element => {
     const path = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'productid=' + element;
     data.push(this.httpClient.get(path));
  });

  return zip(data);
}
```